# spliting numpy array to fixed length

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, split, numpy-ndarray

I have a 1d-numpy array that I want to split to number of sub arrays of fixed length (note it `len`).
When the length of the array is not an multiply of `len` ,I want it to take the last `len` elements of the array.
When using the numpy function `array_split` we get:

```
x = np.arange(8.0)
print(np.array_split(x, 3))
```

The output is:

`[array([0., 1., 2.]), array([3., 4., 5.]), array([6., 7.])]`

But I want:

`[array([0., 1., 2.]), array([3., 4., 5.]), array([5., 6., 7.])]`

Does anyone know a built-in function that does that?

Thnx!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is probably your best bet -

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(8)
c = 3
split = np.array_split(x, c)[:-1] + [x[-int(round(len(x)/c)):]]
print(split)
```

Gives -

```
[array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4, 5]), array([5, 6, 7])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a lenght parameter and list comprehensions:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(8)
lenght=3
split=[x[i:i+lenght] for i in range(0,len(x),lenght)][:-1]+[x[-lenght:]]
print(split)
```

*(do not use len keyword, as it is also a python's built-in)